# Dataframe index rows all 0's

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

I'm iterating through PDF's to obtain the text entered in the form fields.  When I send the rows to a csv file it only exports the last row.  When I print results from the Dataframe, all the row indexes are 0's.  I have tried various solutions from stackoverflow, but I can't get anything to work, what should be 0, 1, 2, 3...etc. are coming in as 0, 0, 0, 0...etc.

Here is what I get when printing results, only the last row exports to csv file:

0
0  1938282828
   0
0  1938282828
   0
0  22222222

```
infile = glob.glob('./*.pdf')

for i in infile:
    if i.endswith('.pdf'):
        pdreader = PdfFileReader(open(i,'rb'))
        diction = pdreader.getFormTextFields()
        myfieldvalue2 = str(diction['ID'])
        df = pd.DataFrame([myfieldvalue2])
        print(df)`
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are replacing the same dataframe each time:

```
infile = glob.glob('./*.pdf')

for i in infile:
    if i.endswith('.pdf'):
        pdreader = PdfFileReader(open(i,'rb'))
        diction = pdreader.getFormTextFields()
        myfieldvalue2 = str(diction['ID'])
        df = pd.DataFrame([myfieldvalue2]) # this creates new df each time
        print(df)
```

Correct Code:

```
infile = glob.glob('./*.pdf')
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in infile:
    if i.endswith('.pdf'):
        pdreader = PdfFileReader(open(i,'rb'))
        diction = pdreader.getFormTextFields()
        myfieldvalue2 = str(diction['ID'])
        df = df.append([myfieldvalue2])
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Raj!  It still was printing 0 for all my indexes, but I added 'ignore_index=True' and that small bit worked perfectly your additions!  Awesome thanks again!